# Error: 'pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant' object has no attribute 'get_body_poses_input_port'

Tags: drake

We're building off the Acrobots, Cartpoles, and Quadrotors code found in the textbook, and we are trying to add a pole on top of the drone.

[image: Here is the pole URDF we are using]

[image: Here is our attempt at connecting the drone and the pole/]
We are having trouble with appropriate output and input ports to use. We expected a pole to show up on top of the drone in the MeshCat visualizer, but can't see anything so far.

Comment: It looks like you might be making two different MultibodyPlants?  You should be parsing two different models into the same MultibodyPlant, and then adding a joint that connects the pole model instance to the quadrotor instance, I believe?